# Gettin TensorFlow to work with distributed binary representation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I know how to create an rnn in TensorFlow with a one_hot vector:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])

x_one_hot = tf.one_hot(x, num_classes)
rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x_one_hot, axis=1)
```

But I am not really sure what to do when my input vector has multiple 1s, eg. it could be 11011 as 1 input per time. so: [[11011],[00111],...]

Is there an issue if I would just feed this vector like I would have my one-hot representation? How should I formulate the above then? I feel like I shouldn't use the tf.one_hot function... Not sure how the shape of rnn_inputs (200 x 5 x 2) can be created without one_hot.

(using TF 1.0)

Comment: If all your input values are going to remain boolean (1 or 0) then you can  just reshape each row into `N x 1` vector.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause trouble with the output predictions?

Comment: The output predictions if not binary then you have to scale it between 0 to 1. Divide by max and then train.

Comment: I meant if there are multiple 1's in the vector.